# Как вернуться к циклу while True, который стоит сразу после импорта библиотек?

Tags: python, while

```
import random
import time
attempts = 0

print('Привет! В данной игре тебе предстоит угадать число в диапазоне, который ты введёшь сам.')
time.sleep(0.5)

print('Теперь тебе предстоит ввести диапазон, из которого будут случайным образом выбираться числа.')
time.sleep(0.5)

print('Приступим!')
time.sleep(0.5)
while True:
    first_number = input('Введите начало диапазона: ')
    second_number = input('Введите конец диапазона: ')

    if first_number == second_number:
        print('Числа должны быть разными!')

    else:
        break

first_number = int(first_number)
second_number = int(second_number)

number = random.randint(first_number, second_number)

while True:
    user_number = int(input('Введи число: '.format(first_number, second_number)))

    if user_number < number:
        print('Загаданное число больше введённого ')
        attempts += 1

    elif user_number > number:
        print('Загаданное число меньше введённого ')
        attempts += 1

    else:

        if attempts == 0:
            print('''Вы угадали число! Это было число {}
Вы угадали с первого раза ;)'''.format(number, attempts))
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print('''Вы угадали число! Это было число {}
Было потраченно {} попыток'''.format(number, attempts))
            time.sleep(2)
            break

        answer = input('Хотите повторить игру? Да/Нет: ')
        if answer == 'Да':

            print('Подождите секунду!')


        else:
            print('До скорой встречи')
            time.sleep(1)
            break
```

Comment: Положить первый цикл `While` во второй цикл `While`

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать оператор `return`, но для этого нужно поместить весь цикл в функцию, я затестил код, он работал.

```
def started():
    while True:
        first_number = input('Введите начало диапазона: ')
        second_number = input('Введите конец диапазона: ')

        if first_number == second_number:
            print('Числа должны быть разными!')
        else:
            return

started()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Немного пофантазировал на тему

```py
import sys
from random import randrange

print('Для выхода из игры вместо ввода значения нажмите Enter.\n')


def get_value(prompt: str, separate_block: bool = False):
    if (val := input(f'{prompt}: ')) == '':
        print('Выполнение прервано')
        sys.exit(0)
    if separate_block:
        print()

    sign = ''
    if val.startswith(('-', '+')):
        sign, *l_val = val
        val = ''.join(l_val)
    if val.isnumeric():
        return int(sign + val)

    print('Введено неверное значение')


while True:

    lower_bound = upper_bound = 0

    while lower_bound >= upper_bound:
        while (lower_bound := get_value('Определите нижнюю '
                                        'границу диапазона')) is None:
            pass
        while (upper_bound := get_value('Определите верхнюю '
                                        'границу диапазона', separate_block=True)) is None:
            pass
        if lower_bound >= upper_bound:
            print(
                f'Нижняя граница диапазона не может быть больше или равна верхней .\nПопробуйте еще раз.\n'
            )

    hidden_num = randrange(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1)

    try_count = 1

    while (test_num := get_value(f'Попытка № {try_count}. '
                                 f'Ваше число')) != hidden_num:
        try_count += 1
        if test_num not in range(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1):
            print(f'Введенное число вне диапазона '
                  f'{lower_bound}..{upper_bound}\n')
        elif test_num < hidden_num:
            print(f'Число {test_num} меньше загаданного\n')
        elif test_num > hidden_num:
            print(f'Число {test_num} больше загаданного\n')
    else:
        print(f'Поздравляем! Вы угадали число {hidden_num} '
              f'из диапазона {lower_bound}..{upper_bound} за {try_count} попыток')
        break
```

---

```latex
Для выхода из игры вместо ввода значения нажмите Enter.

Определите нижнюю границу диапазона: 300
Определите верхнюю границу диапазона: 1000

Попытка № 1. Ваше число: 650
Число 650 меньше загаданного

Попытка № 2. Ваше число: 825
Число 825 меньше загаданного

Попытка № 3. Ваше число: 912
Число 912 меньше загаданного

Попытка № 4. Ваше число: 956
Число 956 больше загаданного

Попытка № 5. Ваше число: 934
Число 934 больше загаданного

Попытка № 6. Ваше число: 923
Число 923 больше загаданного

Попытка № 7. Ваше число: 917
Число 917 меньше загаданного

Попытка № 8. Ваше число: 920
Число 920 больше загаданного

Попытка № 9. Ваше число: 918
Число 918 меньше загаданного

Попытка № 10. Ваше число: 919
Поздравляем! Вы угадали число 919 из диапазона 300..1000 за 10 попыток
```